# Proof for the formula: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{r=1}f(\frac{r}{n})=\int^1_0f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

While studying limits, continuity and differentiability in detail for a competitive examination, I chanced upon this useful formula to solve some limit questions:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{r=1}f(\frac{r}{n})=\int^1_0f(x)dx$$
I find it very useful solve to certain limits like: 
$$\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{r=1}\frac{r}{\sqrt{n^2+r^2}}=\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{r=1}\frac{r/n}{\sqrt{1+(r/n)^2}}=\int^1_0\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=\sqrt2-1 $$

---

**However, I wish to**

1. *Prove the identity as well, but I don't know how; how can I prove it?*
2. *Examine other cases*; *for instance, does the below hold true*:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum^{an}_{r=1}f(\frac{r}{n})=\int^a_0f(x)dx$$

Comment: Your formula is missing a $\frac1n$ in front of $\sum$.

Comment: Thank you @JuliánAguirre!  I wrote the question in a hurry; will make sure to correct it and not repeat this again.

Comment: **hint**: What's the definition of $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question probably arises because of the way some textbooks define the symbol $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$. One of the crude definitions adopted in many textbooks (aimed at students of 16 years of age) is like this.

*Let $f$ be continuous on $[a, b]$ and let $F$ be a function such that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ then we define $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a)$$* This is the definition of a *definite integral* in terms of the anti-derivative (and I suspect OP is using this definition). While this definition is highly useful for beginners in evaluating integrals **it is in reality a formula to evaluate the definite integral**.

The proper definition of an integral is done in many ways the simplest of which is offered by Riemann and such an integral is called Riemann integral. The [proper definition](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/07/the-riemann-integral-part-1.html) is slightly technical for beginners (of age 16 years or so). Based on the definition given by Riemann it is possible to prove that if *$f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ then there exists an anti-derivative $F$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ and $$F(b) - F(a) = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{b - a}{n}\sum_{r = 1}^{n}f\left(a + \frac{r}{n}(b - a)\right)$$* If we have $a = 0, b = 1$ we get $$F(1) - F(0) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)$$ The proof however is complicated and is in fact the cornerstone of calculus and the result is often called *The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*. If you are interested in the proof do have a look at [this blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2012/07/the-riemann-integral-part-2.html).

Answer (score 3):

This formula is a result of riemann summations which is used to define integrals.

We know $\sum_{i=1}^{N} f(x_i^*).\Delta_i$ is a riemann sum with $x_i^*$ is in $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$.

They represent finite summations of rectangles (for $1-D$ functions) with width $\Delta_i$, and 
making these widths smaller and smaller we obtain the definition of the integral:

$lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f(x_i^*).\Delta_i = \int_a^b f(x).dx$

Here the integration bounds are $a = x_0$ and $b = x_N$.

Now getting the question re-write $f(\frac{r}{n}) = f(0 + r*\frac{1}{n})$. Setting $\Delta_r = \frac{1}{n}$ 
and $x_r = x_0 + r*\Delta_r$ with $x_0 = 0$ we have:

$lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^{n} f(0 + r*\frac{1}{n}).\Delta_r = \int_{x_0}^{x_n} f(x).dx$

And we can calculate $x_n = x_0 + n*\frac{1}{n} = 1$.

Thus, if you want your integration upper bound to be $a$, then divide the interval $[0,a]$ into $n$ equal sub-interval,
and represend $x_r$ and $\Delta_r$ accordingly.